# Attempt to invoke virtual method TextView.SetText on a null object reference On Fragment

Tags: java, android, validation, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am learning to make an Android application, but I encounter some errors when the application is running.
I use recyclerView inside the fragment because i use Bottom Navigation Menus.

Here is the code.

CustomAdapterRecyclerView.java

```
package com.aphriellart.bri_kredit;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class CustomAdapterRecycleView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapterRecycleView.ViewHolder> { //Error Logcat Here
    private static final String TAG = "CustomAdapter";
    private String[]mDataSet,mDataSet2,mdataSet3;
    private int[]mDataSet4;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private final TextView textnasabah, textjob, textalamat;
        private final ImageView photo;

        public ViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            //Tentukan Click listener for the ViewHolder's View
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Element " + getPosition() + " clicked.");
                }
            });
            textnasabah = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nasabah);
            textjob = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pekerjaan);
            textalamat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.alamat);
            photo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.photothumbnails);
        }
        public TextView getTextnasabah(){
            return textnasabah;
        }
        public TextView getTextjob(){
            return textjob;
        }public TextView getTextalamat(){
            return textalamat;
        }public ImageView getPhoto(){
            return photo;
        }
    }

    //END_INCLUDE(RecyclerViewSampleViewHolder)
    //Inisialisasi Data set
    public CustomAdapterRecycleView(String[] dataSet, String[] dataSet2, String[] dataSet3, int[] dataSet4){
        this.mDataSet = dataSet;
        this.mDataSet2 = dataSet2;
        this.mdataSet3 = dataSet3;
        this.mDataSet4 = dataSet4;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        //buat view baru
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_view, viewGroup,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Element " + position + " set.");
        //dapatkan elemnt dari dataset
        viewHolder.getTextnasabah().setText(mDataSet[position]); //Error Logcat here
        viewHolder.getTextjob().setText(mDataSet2[position]);
        viewHolder.getTextalamat().setText(mdataSet3[position]);
        viewHolder.getPhoto().setImageResource(mDataSet4[position]);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.length;
    }

}
```

And this

BerandaFragment.java

```
package com.aphriellart.bri_kredit;


import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class BerandaFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewFragment";
    private static final String KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER = "layoutManager";
    private static final int SPAN_COUNT = 2;
    private static final int DATASET_COUNT = 60; //menampilkan data sebanyak value

    private enum LayoutManagerType{
        GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER,
        LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER
    }

    protected LayoutManagerType mCurrentLayoutManagerType;

    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    protected CustomAdapterRecycleView mAdapter;
    protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    protected String[] mDataSet, mDataSet2, mDataSet3;
    protected int[]mDataSet4;

    int[]photo = {R.drawable.photothumbnails, R.drawable.photothumbnails, R.drawable.photothumbnails};
    String [] nasabah = {"Michiko","Hell Ember","Blood Queen"};
    String [] job = {"Pemandu Lagu","Tukang Boneka","Rias Pengantin"};
    String [] alamat = {"White Sand Street Asylum","Moonlit River Park","Sacred Heart Hospital"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //inisialisasi dataset
        initDataset();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_beranda, container, false);
        rootView.setTag(TAG);

        //BEGIN_INCLUDE inisialisasi recyclerView
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listpengajuanhariini);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;

        if(savedInstanceState !=null){
            //restore saved layout manager type
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = (LayoutManagerType) savedInstanceState
                    .getSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER);
        }
        setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(mCurrentLayoutManagerType);

        mAdapter = new CustomAdapterRecycleView(mDataSet,mDataSet2,mDataSet3,mDataSet4);
        //mengatur customadapter sebagai adapter untuk recyclerview
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    public void setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType layoutManagerType) {
        int scrollPosition = 0;
        //jika layout manager sudah diatur, ambil scrool position saat ini
        if (mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()!=null){
            scrollPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager())
                    .findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        }
        switch (layoutManagerType){
            case GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER:
                mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),SPAN_COUNT);
                mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
                break;
            case LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER:
                mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
                break;
                default:
                    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                    mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;

        }
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(scrollPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //menyimpan layout manager terpilih saat ini
        savedInstanceState.putSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER, mCurrentLayoutManagerType);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void initDataset() {
        mDataSet = new String[nasabah.length];
        mDataSet2 = new String[job.length];
        mDataSet3 = new String[alamat.length];
        mDataSet4 = new int[photo.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < nasabah.length; i++){
            mDataSet[i] = nasabah[i];
            mDataSet2[i] = job[i];
            mDataSet3[i] = alamat[i];
            mDataSet4[i] = photo[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me please

Thank you

Comment: add the full stacktrace where the null pointer occured

Comment: I have commented where the error occurred